# jQuery load access denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, load

Estou diante de um problema já conhecido por muitos, no IE é possível utilizar o Activex para obter o usuário logado na rede. 

No Chrome isso não é possível e após muitas pesquisas obtive a mesma resposta. 

Sei que há uma bibliotéca no Java que consegue obter esta informação independente do navegador, porém o projeto é pequeno demais e não tenho todo entendimento para utilizar toda estrutura do Java, então deve ser desenvolvido em PHP mesmo utilizando um servidor simples com Tomcat.

Como tentativa de solução foi desenvolvida uma URL utilizando o Java que retorna o usuário e somente o usuário mesmo mais nada.

Porém eu não consigo manipular esta informação tentei via load, ajax, json, jsonp, porém sempre me retornam uma impossibilidade acesso.

Via `$("p").html('<object data="url/login" />')` consigo imprimir a informação na página porém não consigo converte em string para poder utiliza-la.


Se alguém conseguir me dar uma luz como solução para isso seria muito grato. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o `$().load` não é usado para inserir DOM na página, ele é usado para requisições de conteudo HTML gerado pelo back-end para popular elementos no front-end, se quer carregar um elemento object faça assim:

```
$("p").html('<object data="url/login" />');
```

Agora se quer apenas obter informações do back-end de uma requisição acho que o que procura é algo como:

```
$.ajax("url/login", {
    "cache": false
}).done(function(resposta) {
    alert(resposta);
}).fail(function(erro) {
    alert(erro);
});
```

Se os dados do back-end são json, então faça assim:

```
$.ajax("url/login", {
    "dataType": "json",
    "cache": false
}).done(function(resposta) {
    console.log(resposta);//Imprime no console
}).fail(function(erro) {
    alert(erro);
});
```

Comment: O retorno do object era em html mesmo me confundi :).
Agora ao executar o ajax o console me retorna a mensagem: GET http://server2/Usuario/id?_=1473351041784 
user.php:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server2/Usuario/id?_=1473351041784. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://server1' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401. Estou no server 1 e tentando realizar o ajax no 2 há alguma liberação especifica que deve ser feita lá?

Comment: Se utilizado o jsonp o console retorna - id?callback=jQuery1122019…_1473351903903&_=1473351903904:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token - e ao clicar no link consigo visualizar no console o resultado.

Comment: @Cleverson Eu não falei jsonp eu falei json, são duas coisas diferentes. Me diz o teu retorno é json mesmo? Porque se não for não tem sentido usar o dataType

Comment: @Cleverson sobre o `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, esse erro ocorre devido a origens diferentes, leia mais em: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Poisé estou em um servidor diferente creio ser por isso que o json dá erro  de HTTP, vou ler lá.